# On Mac, line endings are automatically being set to Windows line endings, how do I change that?

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, vim, line-endings

Every time I `git commit` anything I get a warning that my files have windows
line endings and that they will be changed to non-Windows line endings.
I don't know why this is even happening in the first place, it seems every file I write in now has windows line endings.
This happens regardless of the editor, it occurs in both Vim and VS Code.
How do I change this back to use Unix line endings?

Comment: Hello! This question may be better suited for https://apple.stackexchange.com/. If you agree, you can [flag it for migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318460/how-to-move-a-question-to-another-site)

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure about that. In [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that “software tools commonly used by programmers” _is_ on-topic. If it were a random macOS command line question, then, sure, other forums would be appropriate, but this seems on-topic to me...

Comment: @Rob Perhaps I'm misreading Aamir's question, but this does not appear to be about any particular "software tool commonly used by programmers." If this question were about, say, git or VS Code, then sure, it could be on topic here. But it seems that Aamir's trouble is with macos itself, so they'd likely get better support on the dedicated site. Plus, with this question being only tagged `macos`, very, _very_ few people will see it here.

Comment: Note that the vim `fileformat` magic is not specific to Mac: it works the same way on Linux, for instance. (I actually disable the recognition of DOS file formats with `set ffs=unix` in my `.vimrc`, but this is probably not something most people want to do.)

Comment: Is the problem restricted to files in a given repository or is it global? If the former (most likely), it is almost certainly caused by misconfiguration of the repository, see [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings). If the latter (*very* unlikely), throw your computer through the window and get a new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both VIM and VS Code recognize whether the file was using macOS/Unix line endings (LF, e.g. `0a` only) or Windows file endings (CRLF, e.g. `0d` followed by `0a`) and preserves that. You can use the terminal `hexdump -C` command and see if your lines are separated by `0d` `0a` or only `0a`.

Most likely, when the files were first created, they were saved with Windows newline sequence, and VIM and VS Code are merely preserving that setting.

- In VIM, when you open/save the file, if the file is currently using the Windows `CRLF`, you'll see a little `[dos]` in the status message at the bottom. If it already is in Unix format, you won't see the `[dos]` there.

  [image]

  In VIM, if it is a `[dos]` file, you can use the `:set fileformat=unix` to convert it to a Unix end-of-line character, and then save the converted file. See [Vim convert file from DOS to UNIX](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2020/12/07/vim-convert-file-from-dos-to-unix/).
- In VS Code, you can set the `eol` setting, but that only affects new files. Again, existing files will preserve whatever end-of-line setting the file originally was using.

  But, if you open a file and look on the status bar, you will see a `LF` or `CRLF` towards the right. You can click on that to toggle back and forth.

  [image]
- For information about how this is handled on the git side, see [Configuring Git to handle line endings](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings). I suspect that you might want to stick with the existing behavior (updating to Unix end-of-line character), but you will see your options clearly laid out in that GitHub doc. But if you really want to keep the CRLF in your files, you can configure your repo accordingly.

Depending upon how many files you have, you might want to find a tool to convert from Windows/DOS end-of-line CRLF sequences to Unix/macOS LF characters. A quick StackOverflow or web search will undoubtedly give you lots of suggestions.

Or, it sounds like your repo has already been updated to Unix-style LF characters, so you might just want to pull and use that.